# mysqli_query() not producing expected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a function being called:

```
function getUnitID($unit_name) {
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
echo '<br/>'.$query = ' SELECT id, unit_name FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "'.trim($unit_name).'"'.'</br>';
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$id = '';
echo 'here';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo 'yup';
    $id = $row['unit_name'];
    if (strlen($id) > 0) 
        echo 'nothing';
    else echo 'something!';
    var_dump($row);
}
mysqli_close($con);
return $id;
}
```

My output is:

```
SELECT id, unit_name FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "a name here"
here
```

However, when I run it in my database I get a row back.

Notice the `echo 'yup';` line doesn't output anything. I assume something with `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);` is messed up, but I know the `$con` is fine because it works in other places.

Comment: either use `LIKE` with wildcards, or just use `=`

Comment: @Dagon I was simply experimenting. I know the difference.

Comment: so the code above is actully what your using or not ?

Comment: I bet you issue an invalid query, with an `<br/>` at the end ... Check the error message returned.

Comment: @Dagon The fact that the query will work regardless if I use `=` or `LIKE` makes it meaningless to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
echo '<br/>'.$query = ' SELECT id, unit_name FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "'.trim($unit_name).'"'.'<br />';
```

Make it like this because i'm pretty sure you mess up the $query:

```
$query=' SELECT id, unit_name FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "'.trim($unit_name).'"';
echo '<br/>'.$query.'<br />';
```

I'm not sure what you are looking for exactly to select but i have another hunch that you want to do this:

```
$query=' SELECT id, unit_name FROM units WHERE unit_name LIKE "%'.trim($unit_name).'%"';
echo '<br/>'.$query.'<br />';
```

Comment: Thanks! I forget that posting on StackOverflow means my technique will get critiqued as well. I will be using `=` as opposed to `LIKE`. I just had posted with the code that I currently had which had just the wildcards removed. And yes @Tieson T., the </br> was a typo.